# Returning before and after values into two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

For the following table I need two scripts to extract two subsequent tables.
The resulting scripts have to be fairly old school and be backwards compatible with SQL2000.
Any advice is much appreciated.

Firstly for each value of CARE_ID I need to return all rows where the EVENT_TYPE is in (CH, TE, BR) and the EVENT_DATE is the last date before the EVENT_DATE of the row where the EVENT_TYPE is SU. There will only ever be one instance of SU for each CARE_ID.

For example - for CARE_ID 6460 this is the row that will be returned

```
CARE_ID   EVENT_ID  EVENT_DATE        EVENT_TYPE
6460      1699      05/01/2014 00:00  CH
```

Secondly what I need is very similar to the above but I need the first instance where the EVENT_TYPE is in (CH, TE, BR) and the EVENT_DATE is the first date after the EVENT_DATE for EVENT_TYPE = SU.

For example - for CARE_ID 6460 this is the row that will be returned

```
CARE_ID   EVENT_ID  EVENT_DATE          EVENT_TYPE
6460      1698      12/03/2014 00:00    CH
```

In both cases if there are multiple rows which cannot be separated by EVENT_DATE because they have the EVENT_DATE on the same date, then the tie breaker is the EVENT_ID. For instances before SU the EVENT_ID value should be the highest, and for instances after SU the EVENT_ID value should be the lowest.

```
CARE_ID EVENT_ID  EVENT_DATE        EVENT_TYPE
3       189       15/04/2010 00:00  SU
3       104       12/05/2010 00:00  CH
3       16        12/07/2010 00:00  BR
3       17        13/07/2010 00:00  BR
3       18        13/07/2010 00:00  BR
39      6         21/07/2009 00:00  CH
39      45        09/10/2009 00:00  TE
78      9         28/07/2009 00:00  TE
78      11        28/07/2009 00:00  CH
95      21        31/07/2009 00:00  CH
95      21        31/07/2009 00:00  TE
151     49        21/03/2010 00:00  TE
217     158       18/02/2010 00:00  SU
217     102       30/03/2010 00:00  CH
355     19        13/07/2010 00:00  BR
355     20        13/07/2010 00:00  BR
355     21        13/07/2010 00:00  BR
355     22        13/07/2010 00:00  BR
355     23        13/07/2010 00:00  BR
355     56        16/07/2010 00:00  TE
355     111       16/07/2010 00:00  CH
364     569       29/01/2011 00:00  SU
364     673       24/08/2012 00:00  TE
367     247       01/07/2010 00:00  SU
369     117       28/07/2010 00:00  CH
369     248       28/07/2010 00:00  SU
380     277       08/07/2011 00:00  TE
631     147       25/12/2009 00:00  CH
631     74        15/01/2010 00:00  TE
631     148       02/02/2010 00:00  CH
1066    472       11/11/2010 00:00  SU
1066    91        15/11/2010 00:00  TE
1661    216       25/01/2011 00:00  CH
1661    217       25/01/2011 00:00  CH
1661    95        01/02/2011 00:00  TE
1661    218       01/02/2011 00:00  CH
1663    97        25/01/2011 00:00  TE
1663    98        01/02/2011 00:00  TE
1663    223       01/02/2011 00:00  CH
1666    100       23/01/2011 00:00  TE
1666    225       01/02/2011 00:00  CH
1805    378       05/03/2011 00:00  CH
1805    383       05/03/2011 00:00  CH
1805    379       06/03/2011 00:00  CH
1805    381       07/03/2011 00:00  CH
2123    769       05/05/2011 00:00  SU
2123    280       10/07/2011 00:00  TE
2222    434       11/05/2011 00:00  CH
2222    513       15/06/2011 00:00  CH
4541    2285      01/02/2013 00:00  SU
4541    1688      04/03/2014 00:00  CH
4711    2300      01/02/2012 00:00  SU
4711    1257      07/02/2012 00:00  CH
4730    1262      22/11/2012 00:00  CH
4730    2303      30/11/2012 00:00  SU
6460    1699      05/01/2014 00:00  CH
6460    3201      10/01/2014 00:00  SU
6460    1698      12/03/2014 00:00  CH
6464    1701      18/12/2013 00:00  CH
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly to make sure it compatible with everything write it in SQL not T-SQL. Also where is the code you have completed so far?